# Get a Image Mask of the Differences Between Two Images Emgu CV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, webcam, masking, emgucv

I was wondering how to take two different gray images and create a mask of the differences between the two.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the camera is stationary and the images are very well, you can find the differences between the two images using element-wise subtraction. Using OpenCV's C++ API, it would look something like this (note: this code is untested):

```
void FindDifference(cv::Mat src1, cv::Mat src2, cv::Mat &dst, int threshold) {
    dst = cv::abs(src2 - src1);
    cv::threshold(dst, dst, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
}
```

You can tweak the value of `threshold` to reduce false positives caused by noise. If you are still getting too many false positives, you should use look into [motion estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_estimation) and [image registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) to align the two images.

I am not familiar with EmuCV's API, but it should be fairly straightforward to translate the above code into its API calls.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It was extreamly easy to translate and it worked pretty much the way I had wanted it to.

Comment: Can you please guide me for eye tracking and blink detection? How to use cv::findContours to get connected components?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any experience with eye tracking. I've heard good things about OpenGaze, but have never used it myself.